# How to merge two pandas dataframes by value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I got two textfiles which I read as pandas dataframes.

df1:

```
  Streetname  energy_consumption
0    Street1                 NaN
1    Street2                 NaN
2    Street3                 NaN
3    Street4                 NaN
4    Street5                 NaN
```

and df2:

```
  Streetname   energy_consumption
0    Street2                   42
1    Street4                  886
2    Street5                    7
3    Street7                   32
4    Street9                  456
```

I want to check if the streetname in df2 exists in df1 as well, and merge or append it if it does. The output should look like this:

```
  Streetname  energy_consumption
0    Street1                 NaN
1    Street2                 42
2    Street3                 NaN
3    Street4                 886
4    Street5                 7
```

I get it to work like this:

```
import pandas as pd

streetname = r"C:\Users\jonas\Desktop\streetname.txt"
street_energy = r"C:\Users\jonas\Desktop\street_energy.txt"

df1 = pd.read_csv(streetname)
df2 = pd.read_csv(street_energy)

df = df1.set_index('streetname').combine_first(df2.set_index('streetname')).reset_index()
print (df)
```

but in the output, I don't want the values from df2 which aren't present in df1:

```
  streetname  energy_consumption
0    Street1                 NaN
1    Street2                42.0
2    Street3                 NaN
3    Street4               886.0
4    Street5                 7.0
5    Street7                32.0
6    Street9               456.0
```

How do I get rid of, in this case, `street7` and `street9` since they're not present in df1?

Comment: You are right, need update. Just tested and added to list of dupes.

Comment: @jezrael that method somehow doesn't take the other columns from ```df2``` with it, just the compared column?